# How can I find the free space available on mounted volumes using Perl?

Tags: perl, diskspace

I'm trying to untar a file. Before untarring I would like to know free space available on the mounted volume. The plan is if there is not enough space I will not untar it! So how can I find the free space available on a mounted volume using Perl? By the way, I'm using Perl for tar and untar.

Everybody is saying about `df` and `dh` but these commands doesn't work on the mount points. What if I want to find the free space that I can write into on a mounted point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using shell commands to generate a single K-free number which Perl can use:

Change into the directory where you want to untar (if not already there) and execute:

```
df . | grep -v '^Filesystem' | awk 'NF=6{print $4}NF==5{print $3}{}'
```

Or replace "." with the actual mount point.

The grep gets rid of the header and the awk prints out the kilobytes available for both split and no-split lines.

This is based on the following sort of output, you may have to adjust if your UNIX outputs something different:

```
Filesystem    1K-blocks      Used  Available  Use%  Mounted on
/dev/sda4     206434224  56965356  139065176   30%  /
varrun          1037296       132    1037164    1%  /var/run
varlock         1037296         0    1037296    0%  /var/lock
udev            1037296        68    1037228    1%  /dev
devshm          1037296        12    1037284    1%  /dev/shm
/dev/sda2         93327     43535      44973   50%  /boot
/dev/sdc1     155056484  29417456  117824612   20%  /media/extra160
gvfs-fuse-daemon
              206434224  56965356  139065176   30%  /home/pax/.gvfs
```

Comment: Using a cpan module to do it is the correct way. You want to avoid shell calls when it's not necessary...

Comment: @Neil, if you look at the source for Filesys::DiskFree, you'll find that all *it* does is call df under the covers. Its portability doesn't seem to extend to Windows Perl which is generally the only reason I would bother to install a CPAN module (since Windows/*IX portability tends to be tricky). Since I tend only to either target Linux or Linux/Windows (I don't usually care about Solaris or BSD), I'd rather do it myself and avoid the necessity of installing another module.

Comment: Does this give the available amount in bytes?

Comment: @Ben, no. As you can see from the second column, it's in 1K blocks.

Comment: @paxdiablo Thanks. On my system the result is simply a number.

Comment: Nor this nor Filesys::DiskFree will work on Centos (6.3, at least)... I suppose it's because on Centos root filesystem is something as long as "/dev/mapper/vg_srvctoklos-lv_root", so the df line is splitted in two lines...

Comment: @Marco, the piping through `awk` is to specifically handle the multi-line version of `df`, as shown,  so I'm not certain why you even made this comment, unless it was meant for one of the other answers.

Comment: @paxdiablo, no, the comment is for the answer :-) I did suspect the awk had that purpouse, but it doesn't work nonetheless: in case of broken lines (NF==5) it returns the available percentage, instead of available k-bytes...

Comment: Then your output is different to what I've shown since $3 is definitely "available kb". I suspect you'll fall under the "you may have to adjust if your UNIX outputs something different" bit of the answer. Alternatively, give `df -P` a try, many have a POSIX mode that forces one line regardless.

Answer (score 13):

You likely want the CPAN module [Filesys::DfPortable](https://metacpan.org/pod/Filesys::DfPortable).

Comment: Doesn't work on Centos (6.3, at least)... I suppose it's because on Centos root filesystem is something as long as "/dev/mapper/vg_srvctoklos-lv_root", so the df line is splitted in two lines...

Comment: Then you want the CPAN module [Filesys::DfPortable](https://metacpan.org/pod/Filesys::DfPortable) which "should work with all versions of Windows (95 and up), and with all flavors of Unix that implement the statvfs or the statfs calls. This would include Linux, *BSD, HP-UX, AIX, Solaris, Mac OS X, Irix, Cygwin, etc ..."

Comment: @geira Thanks for mentioning the [Filesys::DfPortable](https://metacpan.org/pod/Filesys::DfPortable) module. That is the definitive way to go. It is unfortunate that this does not show as the best (or maybe as an alternative) answer for the question of this topic. This is what people finding this page via websearch should see.

Comment: @Keve: Fixed, in a fashion entirely contrary to the nominal way the site is supposed to work and completely consistent with its mission!

Answer (score 2):

You could just use built-in linux commands to get the result:

```
my $vol = "/dev/volume";
my $freespace = `df $vol | grep '$vol' | awk '{print \$4}'`;
# free space in megabytes.
$freespace = sprintf("%01.2f", $freespace / 1024);
```

Comment: Don't use the shell when you don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Filesys::DF](http://search.cpan.org/~iguthrie/Filesys-Df-0.92/Df.pm) (posix system) or [Filesys::DfPortable](http://search.cpan.org/~iguthrie/Filesys-DfPortable-0.85/DfPortable.pm) (Windows also). They both use native code to enumerate FS statistics.