# How can I find the free space available on mounted points?

Tags: perl, diskspace

I have raised [this question previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536160/how-can-i-find-the-free-space-available-on-mounted-volumes-using-perl) but none of the solutions work on the mounted points. Neither `du` nor `df` work on the mounted points. Is there a way to find it out?

Comment: You could have kicked the previous question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what you mean by "doesn't work on the mount points". Change into the directory where you want to untar (if not already there) and execute:

```
df . | grep -v '^Filesystem' | awk 'NF=6{print $4}NF==5{print $3}{}'
```

The grep gets rid of the header and the awk prints out the kilobytes available for both split and no-split lines.

This is based on the following sort of output, you may have to adjust if your UNIX outputs something different:

`Filesystem    1K-blocks      Used  Available  Use%  Mounted on
/dev/sda4     206434224  56965356  139065176   30%  /
varrun          1037296       132    1037164    1%  /var/run
varlock         1037296         0    1037296    0%  /var/lock
udev            1037296        68    1037228    1%  /dev
devshm          1037296        12    1037284    1%  /dev/shm
/dev/sda2         93327     43535      44973   50%  /boot
/dev/sdc1     155056484  29417456  117824612   20%  /media/extra160
gvfs-fuse-daemon
              206434224  56965356  139065176   30%  /home/pax/.gvfs`